# open current view in the Android emulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio Xamarin Forms, and I have two different views in a project called Favorits and MainPage.  Every time I run the emulator it opens the MainPage view, even if the Favorits view is open.

Comment: this is not complete question can you send the code what are you try ?

Comment: With "run the emulator" do you mean "run" from visual studio? Because this will restart the app on the emulator (it has to because it builds and copies another version of your app), so the app doesn't remember which page was open before (unless you're specifically storing the state somewhere on the device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is set the Start ContentPage (or view) in you App.xaml.cs portable project.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //uncomment the one you need

        //MainPage = new Views.MainPage();

        //MainPage = new Views.Favorits();

    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This how its written in my App.xaml.cs file... MainPage = new MainPage();  When I write MainPage = Views.Favorits();  it said Views does not exist in current context... I also tried MainPage =  new Favorits(); and that does not work either

Comment: I dont know your namespace (or project) structure. 

What i said assumes you have a folder named "Views" and inside you have two "ContentPages" called "MainPage" and "Favorits". Now if they are not in the folder (class), then simply do MainPage = new MainPage();